# How can I access an entity's individual property using Apache Olingo?

Tags: java, jpa, odata, olingo

I have a Java web application which implements an OData service, using JPA. This is done exactly as shown in the [Apache Olingo tutorial](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/CreateWebApp.html).

This works well when I retrieve a specific entity, as well as when I retrieve a specific entity instance based on its ID (http://my-backend-url.com/Services.svc/MyEntityName(myID)), however, when I try to access a specific property of this entity instance (http://my-backend-url.com/Services.svc/MyEntityName(myID)/MyProperty), the request fails with a **501: Not implemented** error.

I have been following the Apache Olingo documentation and as far as I understand, I only need to set up the ServiceFactory when using JPA, and this in turn initializes the EDM provider and the JPA Processors. So there would be no need to specifically handle this type of request.

I am using OData v2 which [supports](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#AddressingEntries) individual property addressing.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? I am still very new to Olingo and OData, so please be very detailed in your explanations...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, through thorough debugging I discovered that the ODataSingleProcessor class throws an exception as soon as the readEntitySimpleProperty method is called. So I guess reading a simple property of an entity using the ODataSingleProcessor is never possible. I will probably have to overwrite the processor class to get around it.

Comment: Maybe you can create NavigationProperty and just a single value inside entity where this property navigates.